# Obtain simple numerical values from the output of Mathematica's Solve function

Tags: equation-solving

```
A = 40 acre;
h = 30 ft;
por = 0.3;
Swi = 0.38;
Boi = 1.2;
rf = 0.23;
cr = 3*10^-6  1/psi;
cw = 2*10^-6 1/psi;
co = 5*10^-5 1/psi;
Pini = 6000 psi;
pboil = 930 psi;
porvoli = A h por;
watvoli = porvoli Swi;
OOIP = porvoli (1 - Swi)/Boi;
Np = OOIP rf;
porvol[dp_] = porvoli (1 - cr dp);
watvol[dp_] = watvoli (1 + cw dp);
Bo[dp_] = Boi (1 + co dp);
fmatbal1[Np_, dp_] = (porvol[dp] - watvol[dp])/Bo[dp] == OOIP - Np;
soldp = Solve[fmatbal1[Np, dp], dp] // First // Simplify
Grid[{{"Pressure depletion is", (Pini - soldp)/psi, "psi"}}, 
   Frame -> All] // nf // ScientificFrom
```

Hi, all:
I am a new user of *Mathematica* for only two weeks and this is my first time to Stack Exchange website. When I am trying to use the `Solve` function to solve for `dp`, it works and outputs as this: `{dp -> 3.55842*10^7}`, but when I am trying to calculate the final result (`P_ini-dp`), the `dp` is not in numerical format but still in the original format and output this:

```
{{"Pressure depletion is", {0.00014503774389728312` (4.13*10^7-
(dp -> 3.558*10^7))}, "psi"}}
```

Is there anyway to transfer the `dp` to a numerical value that I can directly use it in the final output format?

Thanks very much.

Comment: All you need is `dp /. soldp`.

Comment: For `soldp`, put `dp /. Solve[...]` instead of just `Solve[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say you just need to use `ReplaceAll` apply on that `Rule`.
In your code, `soldp` is `{dp -> 5161.06 psi}`, what you want is only `5161.06 psi`, in this case `dp /. soldp` would help:

```
Grid[{{"Pressure depletion is", (Pini - dp /. soldp)/psi, "psi"}}, 
   Frame -> All] // nf // ScientificForm
```

There is also a less common way to do the same thing: `ReplaceAll[soldp][dp]`

PS: 
I'm wondering what `nf` stands for and whether `ScientificFrom` actually means `ScientificForm`.

Comment: Hi, it looks like nf will just take the 3 significant figures, and you are right, ScientificfForm is a typo.